# Turn off nearby device scanning programmatically on Samsung Android 7

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, device, scanning

I am developing a bluetooth Android App that need to keep the connection to multiple devices constantly for 24 / 7.
It works fine on any other phones except Samsung phones (S6 / S7 / S8) running Android 7.
However, I found that by turning off "Nearby device scanning" option in "Settings -> Connections -> More connection Settings" helped a lot of the stability. This option seems only exist on Samsung phones with Android 7.

I am wondering on Samsung phones with Android 7, how to programmatically turn off this option in Android Java? (It seems there is no such a public API)
If not possible, how would it be possible to programmatically pop up the intent of "Settings -> Connections -> More connection Settings"?